# change visibility with onmouseover / onmouseout

Tags: javascript, html, css, onmouseout

I'm trying to make an img disappear with an onmouseover event and then I would like that img to reappear with an onmouseout event Here's what i have so far:

```
<body>
    <h1>Catch the Easter Bunny to get your egg!</h1>
    <img src="images/rabbit.png" id="rabbit1" onmouseover=""
         onmouseout="show(this);" alt="Catch the rabbit"/>
    <img src="images/rabbit.png" id="rabbit2" onmouseover="hide(this);"
         onmouseout="show(this);" alt="Catch the rabbit"/>
    <img src="images/rabbit.png" id="rabbit3" onmouseover="hide(this)" alt="Catch the rabbit"/>
    <img src="images/rabbit.png" id="rabbit4" onmouseover="hide(this)" alt="Catch the rabbit"/>
    <h2 id="noeggs">No Easter Eggs for You</h2>
    <h2 id="yousuck">Humans suck!!!</h2>
</body>

var count = 0;

function hide(node) {
    count += 1;
    node.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

function show(node) {
    node.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/jashwant/BxL4m/) works perfectly

Comment: No, it's not. The second image is blinking, and the last two images aren't showed after being hidden.

Comment: @Riateche , look the code closely. Only second image has `show()/hide()` hence its blinking. First image has only `show()` and last two only have `hide()`. It's working absolutely fine.

Comment: yeah how do i get rid of the blinking?

Comment: @Jashwant, I see, but that's not what is expected and I hardly can call it 'works perfectly'.

Comment: It works perfectly based on what user has coded. We can never tell what   OP expects. I was just saying he's coding absolutely fine. `this` and `visibility:none` is not a problem which other answers mentioned. Nevermind, I get your point, you get mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using opacity

```
node.style.opacity=0;
```

or

```
node.style.display='none';
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you expect this to work? When you hide an element, `onmouseout` event will fire immediately after you move mouse cursor somehow, and the element will reappear. This will lead to blinking while cursor is moving. This is obviously not what you want. You should alter opacity instead of hiding elements completely.

And you should properly get target element: see [Cross browser event listeners](http://javascript.about.com/library/bllisten.htm).

Comment: but when you hide an element doesn't it still take up space on the page? This is why I didn't go with display: none;

Comment: It takes. But when you move the mouse out of this place, you're moving over background element. So, mouseover event happens for background element, and mouseout event happens for hidden element because mouse is no longer over it.